# In a "has-a" class relationship does the contained class have to be implemented inside the class . . 

Tags: visual-c++, has-and-belongs-to-many

**In a "has-a" class relationship does the contained class have to be implemented inside the class that contains it or can it be written entirely separately in a different file?**

For example:

let's say:

```
class Pen
{
   public:
   .
   .
   .

   private:
      Ball point;
};
```

Can class Ball be in a separate header file or do I have to implement it *within* class Pen?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Ball` can be in it's own file:

Ball.h

```
class Ball
{
} // eo class Ball
```

Pen.h

```
#include "ball.h"

class Pen
{
private:
    Ball point;
} // eo clas Pen
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be either way. If `class Ball` is not for use only within `class Pen` you should implement it separately - as a separate class in the same file or in another file.

Anyway C++ doesn't care how many files the implementations reside. Do as it feels convenient.